# How to select text in Illustrator to view font face?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an Illustrator file and the graphic has text. When I select anything, all I get are paths.

I'd like to see what font is being used in the text. How is that done?

Comment: not asked, but you have met the method which designers use to avoid "no such font installed" problems, font software pirating problems and sometimes also "you have edited my design illegally, you must buy updated versions and pay for them"-problems. If one saves a file without converting texts to paths , the texts stay editable and the font is included (=embedded) to the Ai file. One can prevent font embedding because it's illegal to distribute fonts, but then the file can be unreadable elsewhere or the font is substituted automatically with something which does not fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have received the document with the outlined text there is no way back, unless you can ask who designed it.

To keep the font info there must be an editable text in the document. If selecting the whole document there are only paths, this means the text is transformed into paths too, it's not more editable, so the information about the typography is lost.

An option is to select that text, copy and paste it in a new document, export it as a .jpg file and use some font identification service like the list described in the [questions requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/120647).

Comment: It's a .ai file. You are saying that once you create something in Illustrator and save it, there's no way to identify the text thereafer?

Comment: Answer updated...

Comment: @4thSpace not really just that once somebody destroys the connection to what it was originally there s no going back.

Comment: The original design file *probably* still has the text as editable text - odds are high this is a version of that file destined for *distribution* only, not further design, with all fonts "blown to outline" and most graphics "flattened" or in some cases "expanded" - this is typically done for three reasons: 1) to improve reliability of appearance on someone else's computer, 2) to avoid font embedding issues / liability, 3) to keep the uninitiate from editing inappropriately 3a) to keep a cheapo client from trying to edit work versus returning to the cheapo designer.